# Integer.toString(int a) v. int a +"" v. String.valueOf()

Tags: java

In Java an int can be converted into a String in to ways

```
String number = Integer.toString(6);
```

or

```
String number = 6 + "";
```

or

```
String number = String.valueOf(6);
```

Two use a function, and one is concatenation, but all achieve the same goal,
Which is better to use? and which one is more efficient? Or do they all end up funneling to a single function? or does the compiler just end up swapping them out for the same function in the end?

Comment: Useless concatenation *might* be JITted away eventually, but ew.

Comment: Unless you're doing a _lot_ of them in a loop, my opinion is it's most efficient just to use `String number = 6 + "";` as it looks cleaner and is shorter to type. Most likely it will have zero noticeable effect on execution.

Comment: `String.valueOf(int)` will call internally `Integer.toString` so "it is the same". The concatenation will end in 3 resources being built.. the 6, the "" and the result "6". While toString will build the string using chars and offset.. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%29

Comment: Even in a loop you are very likely to see no difference. But as long as both `""` and the number are constant like with `6+""` it is the most efficient solution as it is also a constant. It is even true that `(6+"") == "6"`

Comment: I think it depends on developer which approach will use. I cannot tell you why you shouldn't use concatenation. I usually use `<number value> + ""` but when i know that i will have hard work with Strings since they are immutable i usually use StringBuilder.

Approaches you mentioned in question have same result but looks differently. I think there is not rule that exactly says *"you shouldn't use concatenation"*

Only thing i can say for sure is that approaches except concatenation are "cleaner".

Comment: Well it may seems as duplicate but OP is asking about `6+""` so it is `int` literal, not `int` variable. In this case Java7 compiler will convert it to string in compilation type so it would be the same as writing `"6"` so it is the best option here. But in case if we would like to convert `int` variable like `String tmp=i+""` then compiler would change it to `String tmp = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(i)).toString();` so simply calling `Integer.valueOf(i)` would be better since `String.valueOf(i))` uses it internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.valueOf` calls `Integer.toString`: http://www.mavenjava.com/sun/jdk/1.6.0/src/java/lang/String.java.html#String.valueOf%28int%29

```
public static String valueOf(int i) { 
    return Integer.toString(i, 10); 
}
```

`String number = 6 + "";` uses a StringBuilder and appends:

> String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.

(which is inherently slower than the other two ways).  The best bet is to directly use `Integer.toString`

Comment: `6 + ""` is a compile time constant => no StringBuilder, just a hardcoded constant...

Comment: @assylias Strictly speaking, the spec does not require that simplification

Comment: Neither does it strictly require a StringBuilder.

Comment: @UFL1138 The aforementioned quote is actually from the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: That is a fair point.

Comment: @Nirk I am aware that it may use StringBuilder and/or StringBuffer, but as has been pointed out, the compiler may optimize 6+"" into "6", in which case no SB is necessary.

Comment: @UFL1138: The compiler *must* turn `6+""` into `"6"`. That’s part of the Java specification. The result is a *compile-time constant*.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

Comment: It is interesting that there is no mentioning of StringBuilder or StringBuffer in the [String Class Javadocs of JDK 1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo: I clearly see in that document: *The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.*

Answer (score -2):

You should avoid String concatenation whenever you can, especially if it's in a loop.  That said, a lot of times it's easiest code-wise to use `""+6`.  `String.valueOf(6)` is probably the best option.  Under the hood concatenations get turned into a `StringBuilder`, so there's more overhead there than if you use `String.valueOf(6)`.  `Integer.toString(6)` is just weird IMO.  Also if it's a literal you should just use `"6"`.

Comment: Why is it "just weird"? To me it seems more semantic.

Comment: Do you have a reference about how string concatenation is implemented as StringBuilder under the hood? I'd love to read about that.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo There was a fair amount written about StringBuilder when it replaced StringBuffer; some searching should turn up enough info.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo it is the case - javac does it for you...

Comment: Have you ever used it instead of one of the other options?  I certainly haven't.  It's weird in one sense because toString usually takes no parameters.  The other is that it's easy to confuse it with toString(int,int) that converts it to a given base instead of the default of 10.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2

Comment: Well, since concatenation is implemented at the language level and not at the API level, I have not found any reference like that in Javadocs, neither I remember that in JLS. Not even String.concat is implementat that way. So I am rather courious to read that reference.

Comment: @UFL1138 I *always* use it instead of the other options, although in general I use templating instead. It's not easy to confuse it with a method that takes another parameter, and that there's a variant including the base makes it *more* semantic, not less. Plus you're converting an `int` (suspiciously close to `Integer`), and to me, the "value" of an integer *is* the integer, not a string.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo The *syntax* is implemented at the language level, the code that's *generated* can be whatever the Java compiler wants.

Comment: @Dave Newton So, what you are saying is that if I decompile the code in the question I will see a StringBuffer instead of String being used?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo In many cases, yes.  Did you know you can use `javap -c` to view the byte code?

Comment: I guess my point here is that, according to the shared reference, there may be situations (not always) in which a Java compiler implementation may choose to do concatenation using StringBuilder. But I do not see that happening for the particular scenario of this questions and so, I think it cannot be categorically affirmed that it will be done with StringBuilder. We would need to discuss a particular JVM and compiler implementation to be sure of that.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo: “ if I decompile the code in the question I will see a StringBuffer instead of String being used”? No. You will see that `6 + ""` has turned into `"6"`

Comment: @Holger The reference shared above says: "To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression" How can I verify that for this particular compiler using the example on the question this is what the compiler did? I can decompile the code and check, and if I do not see StringBuffer, then, does it mean it did not use it? Then the statement on the answer is wrong.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo No, I'm not saying that at all. I'm saying a compiler can generate whatever code it wants for string concatenation, including using a StringBuilder. In this case the compiler sees that it's just constants and doesn't need to use anything other than the already-converted constant.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo: For the concatenation of compile-time constants the compiler *must* compute the result and create a compile-time constant. For all other concatenations involving variables (not containing a compile-time constant) the compiler *should* use a `StringBuilder`. But note that even variables might be a compile-time constant, e.g. `final int var=6;`